# Configure Azure Web Server logs to save IP anonymously or not at all

Tags: azure, logging, azure-web-app-service

I've got a little Web Site in Azure. Until now, I used the "Diagnostics logs" to be able to do a little bit of analyzing for my web site (what pages are visited most etc.). I had set "Web server logging" to "Storage".

[image: Screenshot of Azure Diagnostics Logs.]

In few days, the General Data Protection Regulation (GDPR) of the European Union will take effect. It does not allow to save "personal data" if it is not necessary. IP addresses are - unfortunately - "personal data" as defined by the GDPR. As an exception, they allow to save IP addresses in logs for 7 days (to be able to fight DDOS attacks etc.) but not longer.

I could configure the logging to a retention period of 7 days, but this would mean that all the information (not only IP addresses) will be lost after 7 days.

There are German hosters who solve the problem by making the IP addresses in the logs anonymous after 7 days. (Either by deleting the last two parts of the IP address or by completely erasing them)

For me it would be sufficient if the IP addresses would never be saved or always saved in an anonymized way.

Is there a way to configure the Azure Web Server logs in such a way? (I mean I don't think I am the only customer from the EU.)

Answer (score 0):

Actually, web server log just could choose which storage you store in.

> There are German hosters who solve the problem by making the IP addresses in the logs anonymous after 7 days. (Either by deleting the last two parts of the IP address or by completely erasing them)

After storing in storage, you could **download it and try to make the IP address in log anonymous then upload it to another storage**.

And you could **manually set a timer** to anonymize IP address everyday.

So that you could always save IP address in an anonymized way.